# Positioning Django objects, with template for loop tags *Struggling to replicate Instagram push and pop of photo location *

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-templates

I am having difficulty positioning the photo location after a user posts a photo, where the (Purple Gameboy Photo) goes where the (Mansion Photo) is, and where the (American Football Player Photo) goes where the (Purple Gameboy Photo) is, just like Instagram's profile. Where the most recent go to the top left of the photos, and the last posted photos get pushed down to the bottom right

The function checks the first iteration of the for loop and creates a row and column for the first photo, the American Football Player Phot is the first photo posted, then moves along until the fourth photo comes in. Rather than poping the oldest photo to a new row and pushing the newest photo to the front of the existing row. It keeps the location of the first photo and creates a new row for the latest photo.

Profile_Page.html

```
    <!-- -----------------------------------------ALBUM SECTION---------------------------------------- -->
    <div class="album-section">
      <h2>Albums</h2>
      {% for x in img %}
          {% if forloop.first %}
          <div class="row ">{% endif %}
              <div class="col-4 col-4 col-4" >
                  <div class="text-center mt-2">
                      <a href="{% url 'single_page' x.id %}" ><img src="{{x.file.url}}" href="{% url 'single_page' x.id %}" height="100%" width="100%"  class="myImg"></a>
                  </div>
              </div>
              {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
          </div>

          <div class=row>{% endif %}
              {% if forloop.last %}
          </div>{% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Style.css

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

[image]

Comment: remove the row-reverse and what happens? Are you ordering your images in the view or model with most recent first?

Comment: If I remove row-reverse it just mirrors the position of all the pictures except the middle. And I'm not ordering my images in my views.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the question, but setting `flex-direction: row;` and ordering the images in descending order by date added should give you what you want I think.

Comment: I just tried that it didn't work, but I was wondering if you know how to start at the end of a for loop for the django templates?

Comment: Post the code for your view; that may help.

Comment: Order your img in descending order by adding `order_by('-id')` to your img queryset or use a date field if you have one on the model.

Comment: That was worked dude, thank you so much.